# How to Inherite mvc contoller to base controller in MVC 5.2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my home controller and I m using MVC 5.2.3 version

```
 public partial class HomeController : BaseController
{
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();//here will get the error View Name does not find the current context
    }
}
```

and this is my base controller

```
 public partial class BaseController : Controller
{


}
```

And I get the error like Index action View name does not exist in the current context.
Please help me how to solve.

Comment: Did you create View for this Action?

Comment: Hi Eugene D.
Yes I created view also.when I just inherite direct contoller so work but when i put basecontroller so getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the path to view is not correct. This code works for me:

**Controllers:**

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
 {
 }
 public class ContactUsController : BaseController
 {
    [Route("contact-us")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("disclaimer")]
    public ActionResult Disclaimer()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
  //IHome_Repository _IHome_Repository = new Home_Service(new WebAppDBEntities());
  //  SEO SEO = new SEO();

 // [Sitemap(Frequency = SitemapFrequency.Hourly, Priority = "1.0", IsRemoveParameter = true)]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string specificconveter)
 {
    return View();
 }
 public async Task<ActionResult> download()
 {
      return View();
 }
}
```

**View path:**
[image]

Comment: Yes right but I have create one other controller and name like basecontroller to inherited all the controller . when we create same controller then work but I should separate controller with inherit every controller

Comment: @alpesh ramani. Sorry, I didn't get you. You can add BaseController separately and then inherited all you controllers from it. And then add View result to all of these controllers. Please tell me if you need more explanation. I can edit the answer and provide another example of code

Comment: Yes please open this link and see all the code
https://pad.riseup.net/p/alpesh